# Unable to access website via hostname, but able to access via IP

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ubuntu-14.04

this is probably a newbie question, but I won't learn if I don't ask :)

I have a ubuntu webserver that hosts my website, and I have a no-ip account that provides the hostname.

I was able to access the website earlier today, but now I am unable to access via the hostname via my laptop, or smartphone. When I do a ping, it cannot resolve the hostname. When I do an nslookup on the hostname, it times out.

I am able to resolve via my external IP address, the internal IP address, as well via the webservers hostname, which confirms that apache is up on the server, and that the webserver is at least on lol.

I think it's a DNS issue, but I'm not sure what to check from here to be sure. Please advise if any more information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the IP address that the hostname resolves to match your external IP address ?

Comment: @Lawrence the hostname corresponds to the correct IP address on the no-ip settings page, but does not resolve when I try to access it, and the internal hostname resolves to the internal IP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No-ip has been seized by microsoft and 22 no-ip domains (like zapto.org) are down for a while.

Read this: http://www.noip.com/blog/2014/06/30/ips-formal-statement-microsoft-takedown/

Comment: Well there you go. I had no idea either...and I have a zapto.org subdomain too.